# Twilio with Node.js not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, twilio

I'm attempting to use twilio as a way for me to get alerted whenever a data is added to my firebase account ("child_added"). I am using node.js and have installed and followed all instructions to get twilio on my computer. Yet, everytime I run my application, I get the following errors:

```
require.js:1958 GET file:///Users/KV/CS/ErrandBoi2/twilio.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUNDreq.load @ require.js:1958load @ require.js:1682load @ require.js:832fetch @ require.js:822check @ require.js:854enable @ require.js:1173enable @ require.js:1554(anonymous function) @ require.js:1158(anonymous function) @ require.js:134each @ require.js:59enable @ require.js:1110init @ require.js:786(anonymous function) @ require.js:1457
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "twilio"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

In other words, my computer can't find a twilio.js file, which I believe should just be in my node_modules. I have attached my code, please let me know if I am doing anything incorrectly. Since I have aded the lines concerning twilio, my form action to go to "thanks.html" once the submit button is pressed is not working as well.

I've looked everywhere for a "twilio.js" file, but the node instructions tell me to just download the modules through npm. I would essentially like to move the solution to my public website and see if it will work...

```js
// Creates a variable called databaseLink that links to our database.
  var databaseLink = new Firebase('https://errandboi-f1cf5.firebaseio.com/');  
  // Create javascript variables that link our previous HTML IDs.  Remember, we can't use regular HTML inside a script tag, so we need to use JQuery to reference any previous HTML.  A $ means we are using JQuery
  var messageField = document.getElementById('task');
  var nameField = document.getElementById('name');
  var contactField = document.getElementById('contact');
  var locationField = document.getElementById('location');
  var miscField = document.getElementById('misc');
  var messageList = $('#example-messages'); // DELETE MAYBE?????
  // Twilio Credentials
  var accountSid = '[MY_ACCOUNT_SID]';
  var authToken = '[MY_AUTH_TOKEN]';
  //require the Twilio module and create a REST client

  function push() {
    databaseLink.push({
      name:document.getElementById('name').value, 
      task:document.getElementById('task').value,
      contact:document.getElementById('contact').value,
      location:document.getElementById('location').value,
      misc:document.getElementById('misc').value,
    })
    require(['twilio'],function(twilio){
      var client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);
    ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
      var newPost = snapshot.val();
      client.sms.messages.create({ // if "messages.create" doesnt work, try "sendMessage" or "sms.messages.create"
        to:'+13177302557',
        from:'+13173644864',
        body:'You got a new request: \n' + newPost.name + '\n' + newPost.task + '\n' + newPost.contact + '\n' + newPost.location + '\n' + newPost.misc,
      }, function(err, message) {
        console.log(message.sid);
    });
    });
  });
  };
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <!-- Twilio Library imporrted-->
      <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js"></script> -->
      <!--THIS IS NEEDED TO IMPORT FIREBASE LIBRARIES -->
      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
      <!-- THIS IS JUST A NICE LOOKING FONT -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--THIS IS NEEDED TO IMPORT JQUERY LIBRARIES -->  
      <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <!-- THIS IS TO IMPORT MY JS FILE -->
      <script data-main="index" src="require.js"></script>
<!--  <script src="index.js"></script> -->
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <title>Btown Errands</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
         <header>
            <h1 class="title">Btown Errands</h1>
         </header>
         <div id="banner">
            <h2>Your Helping Hand in Every Situation</h2>
         </div>
         <div id="content">
            <p class="content">Ever have an emergency while you are in class? Life has got you all tied up but your tasks won't do themselves? Well, you are at the right place for help. Let ErrandBoi take the stress off your shoulders while you can do what really matters. Simply, fill out the form below with any* task that you may need help with and one of our drivers will help you out as soon as possible!</p>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <div class="form-style-5">
               <form action="index.html">
                  <fieldset>
                     <legend><span class="number">1</span> Your Information</legend>
                     <input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
                     <input type="email" name="field2" id="contact"placeholder="Contact Information (Email, Phone Number, etc.) *">
                     <input type="location" name="field3" id="location" placeholder="Your Location (i.e. McNutt, Hodge Hall, exact address, etc.)*">
                     <input type="text" name="field4" id="misc" placeholder="Miscellaneous Information That May Be Important"></textarea>
                     <label for="job">Urgency:</label>
                     <select id="job" name="field5">
                        <optgroup label="Urgency level: just for us to prioritize properly">
                           <option value="Not Urgent">Low (ETA: Up to an hour)</option>
                           <option value="reading">Normal (ETA: Up to 45 mins)</option>
                           <option value="boxing">Critical (ETA: ASAP!)</option>
                        </optgroup>
                     </select>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset>
                     <legend><span class="number">2</span>Task that needs completion</legend>
                     <input type="text" id="task" name="field6" placeholder="Let Us Know How We Can Help!*"></input>
                  </fieldset>
                  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="push()"/>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: I am trying this out of Google Chrome

Comment: Why are you running this without a webserver?

Answer (score 1):

I use *twiliio* in my app as well and find no isssues. Once you upload the `node_modules` which should contain a `Twilio` directory (Not a *js* file) it should work. For instance if you ran `npm install twilio` on your local system you will see a `node_modules` directory in the path you did the install and within is will have a `twilio` directory. So once you zip up your `index.js` file and `node_modules` it should have all the dependicies it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could just have to do with how you are instantiating the Twilio Rest Client.

In a [node app](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) I built yesterday I've got:

```
var client = new twilio.RestClient(accountSid, authToken);
```

Instead of:

```
var client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);
```

Let me know if that makes a difference.